# SSCollectionViewItem changing image size

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

how to change the SSCollectionViewItem (from SSToolKit) image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SSCollectionViewItem Documentation](http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSCollectionViewItem.html), the `imageView` property is a `UIImageView`. This means you can adjust its size using `bounds` or `frame` or any of the usual suspects for resizing any UIView. For example,

```
myCollectionViewItem.imageView.bounds.size.width = 10.0;
myCollectionViewItem.imageView.bounds.size.height = 10.0;
```

Here, `UIImageView` is a subclass of [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) so it has `bounds`, which is a [`CGRect`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect) so it has a `size`, which is a [`CGSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGRect) so it has a `width` and `height`, both `CGFloats`.